# Why is my MySQL import failing w/ Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook that needs to refresh a database from upstream. It's deleting the existing database, recreating it, downloading the most recent backup of production (in `.sql.gz` format) and attempting to import it. On that last step, I get this:

> TASK [deploy : Database | Load the database from upstream data] ****************
>   fatal: [54_236_190_225]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "\ngzip: stdout: Broken pipe\n"}

The task:

```
- name: Database | Load the database from upstream data
  mysql_db:
    state: import
    target: /tmp/catalog-3-19-16.sql.gz
    login_host: "{{ mysql_host }}"
    login_port: "{{ mysql_port }}"
    login_user: "root"
    login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    name: "{{ mysql_db }}"
```

The `/tmp/catalog-3-19-16.sql.gz` file exists on the server.

What am I be missing?

Comment: "broken pipe" message means that mysql cannot read input. two choices 1) `gunzip -c <file> | mysql <db>` if working than it is a kind of  bug in module 2) shell is not working than you have an issue with your dump file

Comment: Well, it works from the command line so...ugh.

Comment: If I understood correctly https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/commits/devel/database/mysql/mysql_db.py there were changes. Maybe you should update ansible. Try to extract file before or use bzip2: archives `.bz2`

Comment: also look into ssh timeout - that can result in broken pipe, check your `ServerAliveInterval` in ssh config

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can login via terminal with the credential, note that I'm using default port and localhost.

```
 - name: Importing data
   mysql_db:
     name: "{{ db_name }}"
     login_user: root
     login_host: localhost
     login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
     config_file: no
     state: import
     target: /tmp/catalog-3-19-16.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your playbook is perfect.
If you have manually imported the data in db and then trying to check the same with ansible it will fail.
Try deleting the Database first and then create db and run your import task playbook it will work perfectly